Combining Z scores of Correlated Test Results
I have the Z scores of a population of N for M different tests, where N is O(10000) and M is ~50. The results of these test are not independent, but we can produce a reasonable estimate of the correlation between them. Correlations between tests vary significantly.
I want to be able to flag if an individual is statistically significant across the M dimensions by aggregating these M Z scores into a single value, ideally considering the correlations. I am undecided whether these tests should be weighted evenly or if there should be a bias towards more significant indicators.
How can I aggregate these M Z scores to produce a single Z score for each individual, accounting for the correlation between these tests?

The likely simplest way to do so would be to run a PCA on your Z values: Making sense of principal component analysis, eigenvectors & eigenvalues. This captures correlations between them. The first principal components capture most of the variability, and decompose it orthogonally, so the PCs are not correlated any more.
Based on the PCA, I would flag instances that load most highly (both positively and negatively) on the first principal component. Possibly also look at instances that are "more typical" on the first PC, but load highly on later PCs.
One major advantage is that PCA is implemented for most common software platforms.
